How to rig character face made of stiff objects for pose presetss?
I'm more trying to do a face (the triangle and little square next to it) and i'm not sure if i should connect armature to the whole head (the bit above the sphere) including the face or without the face.
sorry if this is a bit unclear. i will explain further if there is any confusion. 

Pose presets can only be applied to armatures, so the face will need to be rigged with the armature one way or another. Whether you make the stiff face components part of the same mesh and deformed normally, or parented to bones as objects, is your choice. I would suggest the former for consistency, but regardless you will need a bone for each component. Said face bones should be parented to the general head bone (already in the armature I see).
